# asp.net dropdownlist onmousehover event fire dropdown display data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, c#-2.0

I have asp:DropDownList control which i want to display data to user who don't want to click on it.
But user only want to make Mouse hover over asp:DropDownList Control.
Is there any possible way to make it without using datalist control or gridview ?
If so let me know it please.

Comment: i suppose you'd have to go for a solution to design a dropdown-like control (which is client-side driven) based on showing/hiding divs or other html elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
        function Open_ddl(ddl) {
            document.getElementById(ddl).size = 5
        }


        function Close_ddl(ddl) {
            document.getElementById(ddl).size = 1
        }

</script>

...

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPostClaim" runat="server" onmouseover="Open_ddl('ddlPostClaim')" onmouseout="Close_ddl('ddlPostClaim')"></asp:DropDownList>
```

This does however create a new problem where the mouseover over the menu items will not highlight them, at least for me.  Nonetheless, it's a start.